# TextBox Validation to put special character while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, inputbox

I have a requirement with the Textbox . When ever I put some values there should be some validation to put "-" in between the values.

Like When I put the value 123456789 in the textbox , it will show me automatically "123-45678-9" or any other format depend upon the business. I am clueless what to do. I need to show "-" while typing value in textbox.

Any idea/ suggession would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: onKeyPress event u can do that, after how many characters u have to do it

Comment: every 3 element I need to do .

Comment: First read about the `.change()` event handler: https://api.jquery.com/change/ then combine that with `String.match()` function http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp and you're done pretty much

Comment: I tried this $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#autoCompleteID").on("keyup",function(event) {
   /* Act on the event */
   var value = $("#autoCompleteID").val();
   console.log(value);
   if(value.length==3 || value.length==6){
    value = value+"-";
    $("#autoCompleteID").val(value);
   }
  });
 });

Comment: but the problem is that when I do fast typing it is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Please have look @ this, customize it according to your need

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="myid" onkeyup="myFun()">


<script>
var counter = 0;
function myFun() {

    counter++;
    if(counter==3)
    {
       var value = document.getElementById("myid").value;
       value = value + "-";
       document.getElementById("myid").value = value;
       counter=0;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which element tag you are using.

If you are using , then you can use the pattern attribute and regex.
I am a bit confused as to what you want exactly; however, here is an example of how to only accept a number like 123-45678-9 in that exact format of 3 numbers then a dash the 5 numbers then a dash and then one number.

[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{1}
This says it will accept any number, the [0-9], for the first 3 spots, {3} with the first number being the minimum and a potential second number being the maximum number of consecutive numbers, then a dash, -, and so on with those rules changing slightly with {5} and {1}.

However, if you only want to include dashes and numbers in your input, you could just use the following regex: "[0-9]|-"

In the end your solution might look something like:

If you are using , there is no pattern attribute you an apply to the element and you will have to use javascript to restrict what type of input pattern to accept.

Comment: Sorry I meant "[0-9]|\-"

Comment: The requirement to type my account no or Credit Card in Text box.

Comment: Then you need a very specific format, what format do you need exactly? Give me all the formats you need and I can write a regex expression for you.
This is an example for a credit card:
1234-5678-9012
The input would be <input pattern="[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{4}" >

Comment: Thats Fine for me , but how can I add it to that.

Comment: What else do you need to add?

Comment: I am talking about regex. How can I add this regex to input box ?

Comment: Copy and paste this:
<input pattern="[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{4}" >